# override targetNamespace in xjc

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

My issue i that I have 2 versions of my webservice and I would like to separate the classes generated by jaxb into two distinct packages.

To solve this issue I'm trying to override the target namespace of my xsd schema in my xjb file. In order to change the package of the generated classes without altering the wsdl and the schema.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing XmlType.namespace using jaxb bindings during type generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599910/replacing-xmltype-namespace-using-jaxb-bindings-during-type-generation)

Answer (score -1):

You can configure target package using bindings, for instance:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation=".../mySchema.xsd" 
        node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.acme.mypackage"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

You don't need to override the target namespace for this.